# No image on TV when connected using HDMI cable to MacBook pro when booted in bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, hdmi, television

I have a MacBook Pro with an NVidia GT 330M graphics board and mini display port output.

I purchased an HDMI converter for the computer, and connected it to my TV (Panasonic GT30). When booted in OSX, the TV displays the image correctly.

However when booting in bootcamp, there is no image on the TV, it's just black. The display drivers can see that a Panasonic TV is connected, and I can select from the possible display resolutions, but the monitor just remains black.

I downloaded and installed the NVidia reference drivers (don't know if it was a bad idea, but one of the points was to be able to display stereoscopic 3D).

Why is the monitor black?

Edit: I tried connecting to an older Sony TV. Same result, the NVidia drivers can detect that a Sony TV is connected, but the TV is black. I also tried selecting different resolutions and refresh rates, no luck there either.

The bootcamp install is running Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, I'm not sure exactly what I did in what order, but based on my Firefox download history, I think this is what I did.

First I downloaded and intalled version 285.62 (285.62-notebook-win7-winvista-64bit-international-whql.exe). This version gave me the symptoms described in the question.

I then uninstalled all NVidia drivers, which I assumed rolled the driver back to the Bootcamp driver version.

I then downloaded and installed driver verion 260.99 (260.99_notebook_winvista_win7_64bit_international_whql.exe). Now the HDMI output works in my Bootcamp installation.